# How I can make this python script to run on macOS?

Tags: python

```
import time
import pygetwindow as gw
import datetime

def detect_close(window_title):
    while True:
        try:
            windows = gw.getWindows()
            window_titles = [window.title for window in windows]
            
            if window_title not in window_titles:
                print(f"Window '{window_title}' is closed.")
                # Add your code here to perform actions when the window is closed
                current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                print(current_time)
                break
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            break

detect_close("Google Chrome")
```

The above code is not working in macOS. I want to calculate the time when an application is closed on a system.

Comment: What happen when you run this on mac?

Comment: Error: module 'pygetwindow' has no attribute 'getWindows'.
It is showing the above error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pygetwindow` but as far as I can see `getWindows` doesn't exist. I could only find `getWindowsAt(x, y` and `getWindowsWithTitle(title)`.

Comment: Error: module 'pygetwindow' has no attribute 'getWindowsWithTitle'
I am getting the above error when I used getWindowsWithTitle(title)

Answer (score -1):

Have tried using pygetwindow version 0.0.9, you can try:

```
try:
    import pygetwindow as gw
    chrome_window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Google Chrome')[0]
    chrome_window.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```